# how to check failed and terminated jobs

Tags: shell, unix

How to write a shell script for checking failed and terminated jobs in a particular directory  for every one hour. if any failure we need to get one mail ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands

For current jobs used

```
user@mysystem:~$ jobs
```

and termination use

```
user@mysystem:~$ fg
```